# How to display additional data of a selected option in select tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select, angular-material

This is the requirement where the `id` and the `device` has to be displayed alongside the selected option. How to display this additional data using Angular material select.

Note: Not in the option but in selected input tag

```
       <mat-select required formControlName="sensorId">
          <mat-form-field class="w-100">
            <mat-label>
              <em class="fa fa-search f-20"></em>
            </mat-label>
            <input matInput #sensorFilter />
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let sensor of sensors | filter: sensorFilter.value"
            [value]="sensor.name"
          >
            {{ sensor?.name | translate }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
```

This is the sensor object properties

```
public static fields: Array<string> = [
    'id',
    'object_id',
    'unit_type',
    'device',
    'sensor_type',
    'name'
];
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im87l.png)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply need to add the id and device id as an interpolation in the `mat-option` element. Something like this:

```
<mat-option *ngFor=" let widget of widgetsEnum | filter: widgetFilter.value" [value]="widget.id">
      {{ device.id }} {{ widget.id }} {{ widget.name }}
</mat-option>
```

Since there is no 'device' or 'device id' shown in your code, I will assume that it is available in your controller and is called `device`. If not you will need to make it available in the controller and give it the appropriate name. I am also assuming that when you say 'id' you mean the widget id since there is no other id listed in your code.

Comment: Apologies for not explaining in detail. The sensor device id  and sensor id should be displayed in select input when user selects a sensor not in dropdown